# Visual Studio's amazing disappearing interface elements

Tags: visual-studio, winforms

I'm building an interface in Visual Studio. All fine and dandy. Then yesterday I did some resizing and had a crash, not sure which of those caused it, but now the progress bar I was using has vanished from the form. I'm not getting any compile errors, so as far as I can tell it still exists and is just playing hide and seek with me.

Is there any good and clever way to find a object you've hidden from yourself so you can reposition it/make it visible again?

Cheers.
-Stuart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Document Explorer which shows a hierarchy of the controls on your form (and can be used to select it and set properties in the property window). However in the event where I've encountered this bug, it generally had required me to delete the designer code for the missing control and drop a new one to the form.

Comment: In this instance, I was able to find it.

Under the designer I found that the drop down on the properties window listed the object. from there I was able to select it and found it had somehow been moved about an inch below the workable area, into null white space. Used the "Dock to..." property to get it docked to the bottom of the form and back where I could manipulate it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome, this bug is very annoying when it happens, luckily it is not too bad. Also, You may want to make sure you mark answers, this ensures that people looking for a similar answer can find it more easily on the site :)